# Import error when running an Ansible Playbook with a Python module

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to run ansible-playbook with these Python modules:
https://github.com/dkorn/manageiq-ansible-module/tree/master/library

and I am failing with the following error:

```
  from manageiq_client.api import ManageIQClient as MiqApi
ImportError: No module named manageiq_client.api
```

Now, I understand that I simply need to pip install the manageiq_client on the machine I run on but it is something I actually cannot do because I don't have root access to it to install anything. 
I was told to use this [script](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/hacking/test-module):

But I am not sure how.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That [hacking/test-module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/hacking/test-module) script is for [developing a module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules.html) but it bypasses some of the ways ansible executes modules.  If you just want to run a module / a playbook, don't use this.

So your problem is just installing a module as non-root, and having the python ansible executes pick it up.  Options to try:

- `pip install --user`
- run in a `virtualenv`
- set PYTHONPATH manually (slightly tricky to be sure you're only adding...)
- found a [tip in the FAQ](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-python-pathing-not-having-a-python-2-x-in-usr-bin-python-on-a-remote-machine) how to override python interpreter for modules.  If you point it to a virtualenv's `bin/python`, you can have ansible executed "outside" the venv while the module runs "inside" the venv:

  ```
  virtualenv /tmp/v  # can be anywhere
  /tmp/v/bin/pip2 install manageiq_client
  ansible-playbook --extra-vars ansible_python_interpreter=/tmp/v/bin/python2 add_provider.yml
  ```

  (you can also set `ansible_python_interpreter` in inventory file)